# How to mutate a variable using str_pad in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pad

I want obtain as result for df$y `"01", "02", "03", "40h"`, but I can't understand my error:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4),
                 y = c("1","2","03","40h"))
    df %>%
      mutate(y = if_else(length(y) < 2, str_pad(width=2, pad="0"), y))
    #> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `y`.
    #> x argument "string" is missing, with no default
    #> i Input `y` is `if_else(length(y) < 2, str_pad(width = 2, pad = "0"), y)`.
    Created on 2020-10-20 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: Try `str_pad(y, width=2, pad="0")`. You missed to pass the string as first argument.

Comment: @stefan Even if I do `str_pad(y, width=2, pad="0"` there is also an error.

Comment: Simply do `mutate(y = str_pad(y, width=2, pad="0")`. The issue is with length(y). What you want is `str_length(y)`. But in my opinion it is not necessary, as str_pad will only add "0" to strings with length < width

Comment: @stefan Thank you, it works. I thought that I had to select first strings with length < 2.

Comment: You want nchar, not length.

Comment: @zx8754 You're right. Now even my first (redundant) formulation works.

Comment: No problems, great, let's close this post as "typo/read the manuals".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three issues. You need to get rid of `length(y) <2`. The `length` function returns the number of elements in a vector, not the number of characters in a string. If you absolutely want to check the number of characters, use `nchar()`.

Second, you don't need to get the number of characters. The `width` argument for `str_pad` sets the expected number of characters in the output. If the input element is already the same number of characters or more as `width`, it is unchanged.

Finally, the usage of `str_pad` is:

```
str_pad(string, width, side = c("left", "right", "both"), pad = " ")
```

The first expected argument is the string. If you don't put the `string` first, it does not know where to look for it. You have `y` outside the call to `str_pad`. Either put `y` as the first argument or specify `string = y` in `str_pad`.

```
 df %>%
   mutate(y = str_pad(string = y, width = 2, pad = "0")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 01   
2     2 02   
3     3 03   
4     4 40h
```